# Django ORM JOIN postgresql type casting

Tags: python, django, postgresql, generic-foreign-key

I am trying to use Django's reverse generic relation for accessing and filtering related objects via Django's ORM. See below declared models:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models


class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    hst_entries = GenericRelation("myapp.StatusHistory", related_query_name="package")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class StatusHistory(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    object_id = models.TextField()
    object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    entry_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.content_type} - {self.object_id}: {self.status.name}"
```

As you see there is generic relation between `Package` and `StatusHistory` models. For accessing related packages from `StatusHistory` model I tried:

```
StatusHistory.objects.filter(package__name__startswith="pack")
```

And result:

```
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: text = integer
LINE 1: ...kage" ON ("myapp_statushistory"."object_id" = "myapp...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I understand that PostgreSQL is complaining about type mismatch between `object_id` (of `StatusHistory` model) and `id` (of `Package` model) fields. This mismatch can be solved by PostgreSQL cast operator `::` as below:

```
### WRONG
join myapp_package on (myapp_statushistory.object_id = my_app_package.id)

### RIGHT
join myapp_package on (myapp_statushistory.object_id = my_app_package.id::varchar)
```

Is there possible way to make such casting via Django's ORM?

**Note:** Converting `object_id` field to `IntegerField` is not an option for me.

Comment: Well the problem is that the primary key of the `Package` is not a `TextField`, and hence the problem with the types. You can define an `id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)` for `Package`. But right now the two simply do not match.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem isn't there alternative solution other than matching types of these two fields in database? I am seeking a way to solve this problem without altering the tables and through Django's ORM.

Comment: no, Django JOIN logic does not allow casting. I would also consider it bad design to be honest to do casting, since the two types have a different equivalence relation. For example in an integer field `001` and `1` are the same, but in a text field `'001'` and `'1'` are different these are not. It thus makes uniqness constraints impossible.